# How to show these three equivalent statements? (Graph Theory)

Tags: graph-theory, trees

Show that the following statements are equivalent.

1. $G$ is connected and has $n-1$ edges.
2. $G$ is a forest and has $n-1$ edges.
3. $G$ is a tree.

A $Graph$ is said to be connected if every pair of distinct vertices is joined by a path.

A $Tree$ is an undirected, connected graph containing no cycles.

A $Forest$ graph is an undirected graph in which any two vertices are connected by at most one path. Equivalently a forest is an undirected acyclic graph.

Our graph $G$ here is a simple graph with $n$ vertices.

I am confused where to start. Please help me show these.

Comment: What is your definition of a tree?

Comment: Please tell us what you know about this problem.  What is your definition of a tree?  What equivalent definitions do you know about?  Also, somewhere you need to say that $G$ is a simple graph with $n$ vertices for the question to make sense.

Comment: Please do help me, I am new to this. I am confused.

Comment: When proving an equivalence between propositions, one usual way to do is proving that one implies the next. In this example, you'd need to prove $1$ implies $2$, $2$ implies $3$ and $3$ implies $1$. For example, $3$ implies $1$ just needs you to prove that every tree has always $n-1$ edges. Try to do it (draw some examples to see why this would be true), and if you're still confused try to comment here what's confusing you. The same with the other implications.

Comment: Well, a tree is connected and a forest, so if you prove that a tree on $n$ vertices has $n-1$ edges, you will have proved both $3\implies 1$ and $3\implies 2$.  To go in the other direction you must prove that a connected graph with $n-1$ edges is acyclic and that a forest with $n-1$ edges is connected.